# Escape characters in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, escaping, nsmutabledictionary

When i pass an NSString as object for a key in an NSMutableDictionary it seems to contain escape characters as regular characters. How can I remove them? I have tried stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\" withString:@"" byt it does not work.

Here is my code and output:

Code:

```
NSString* fql1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE distance(latitude,longitude,\"%@\",\"%@\") < 1500 AND checkin_count > 5", latitude, longitude];
    NSString* fql2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT author_uid, post_id, timestamp, tagged_uids, message FROM checkin WHERE page_id IN (select page_id from #PlaceQuery)"];
    NSString* fql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"PlaceQuery\":\"%@\",\"CheckInQuery\":\"%@\"}",fql1,fql2] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];


NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"queries"];

NSLog(@"%@", fql);
NSLog(@"%@", params);
```

Output from NSLog(@"%@", fql):

> {"PlaceQuery":"SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE distance(latitude,longitude,"37.331693","-122.030457") < 1500 AND checkin_count > 5","CheckInQuery":"SELECT author_uid, post_id, timestamp, tagged_uids, message FROM checkin WHERE page_id IN (select page_id from #PlaceQuery)"}

Output from NSLog(@"%@", params):

> {
>       queries = "{\"PlaceQuery\":\"SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE distance(latitude,longitude,\"37.331693\",\"-122.030457\") < 1500 AND checkin_count > 5\",\"CheckInQuery\":\"SELECT author_uid, post_id, timestamp, tagged_uids, message FROM checkin WHERE page_id IN (select page_id from #PlaceQuery)\"}";
>   }

I have been searching for hours for a solution so thanks A LOT in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue about permissions... yes, embarrasing...
What confused me was that the escape characters was in the response output...

Thanks @williham and @nielsbot

Answer (score 0):

NSLog escapes strings when they're printed out--you probably don't actually have escape characters in your string.

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%s\n", [ string UTF8String ] )
```

and see what happens...

Comment: Or rather, `NSArray` escapes characters when printed using `-description`, which is called by `NSLog`. It's a small point, but occasionally important.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for answering!

Well, somehow the escape characters (\) seems to be there. I send the dictionary in a request to facebook. The request fails and this is part of the error message:
{
        key = queries;
        value = "{\"PlaceQuery\":\"SELECT page_id FROM place WHERE distance(latitude,longitude,\"37.331693\",\"-122.030457\") < 1500 AND checkin_count > 5\",\"CheckInQuery\":\"SELECT author_uid, post_id, timestamp, tagged_uids, message FROM checkin WHERE page_id IN (select page_id from #PlaceQuery)\"}";

Comment: how are you executing your request? ASIHTTP? What does [ request responseString ] show?

Comment: Hi,
I think I might be sending an invalid request to facebook. Does anyone have some sample code for sending a multiquery fql request using facebook graph api?